# Trouble Converting HTTP Get Requests from WP REST API v1 to v2

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am using the deprecated WP REST API v1 and AngularJS to display data grabbed through the api on a website. We are rebuilding the site and I figured that I would update from v1 to v2. The trouble is that I am unable to receive a response from the server using the new endpoint. Most of my requests involve custom post types.

This works great using version 1:

```
/wp-json/posts?type[]=news&filter[posts_per_page]=10&page=2
```

But updating the request to this (version 2) does not work, it returns an empty array:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?type[]=news&filter[posts_per_page]=10&page=2
```

How do I convert my existing requests into a format that will work with version 2? The documentation at http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/ is a bit confusing and lacks any examples of request that have substance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`curl http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` actually works for me here. You can check this in your browser as well.

--

P.S. sorry to post this as an answer, apparently I don't have enough reputation to post comments.

Comment: I am able to get a response at `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` as well, but that is not what I need. I need to know what the equivalent to `?type[]=news&filter[posts_per_page]=10&page=2` would be in version 2. This example uses a custom post type called `news`.

Comment: Please check the following link for reference. I have the same issue but i can fix it through following documentation link     https://1fix.io/blog/2015/09/29/wp-api-v2-angularjs-theme/